# JavaFX TableView column sorting has three states, why?

Tags: javafx

When I click a TableView's column, and change it sorting order, there appears to be actually three different states for the column. Ascending, descending, and... what? I'm confused.

I've never encountered an application that has such a sorting behavior. Is there a way to remove the third state, so that it just alternates between ascending and descending?

Comment: I'm no expert on JavaFX, but usually (in all the contexts I've seen in my life) the table column may have three states: unsorted, ascending, descending. Check e.g. Wikipedia's tables or JetBrains IDE's tables...

Comment: It's ascending, descending and the column not contributing to the sorting at all. If you provide multiple sortable columns, removing this state is the last thing you want. You could probably add a listener to the `TableView.sortOrder` list and use `Platform.runLater` to add the column again and change it's sort type to ascending, if it's removed, if you really want to go through with this...